# Textview Does not display part of the text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TableLayout` in which includes four rows 
each row has two columns.
I am displaying two TextViews in the rows, one static text and another dynamic text which might have more than 20letters as text.

one of the field is to display the email id and in the `TextView` it displays only a part of email id and misses some part of the text.

How will I display the whole text in the `TextView` without missing any characters.

The `xml` is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/apt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Name :"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tname"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Employee Id:"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tempid"
                    android:layout_width="200dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Designation :"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tdesg"
                    android:layout_width="200dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Status :"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tstatus"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/id5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="Email Id:"
                    android:textColor="#707070"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/temailid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I did try various solutions , nothing seem to work

Comment: reduce textsize it will solve your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your text size is 15 dp, but your TextView width is only 200dip. It seems like the result cannot display more than 20 letters on the one line.  There are three ways I suggest to you:

1. Extend your TextView width or reduce your text size;
2. Set your TextView to multi-line wrapped text mode with `android:singleLine="false"`;
3. If you want to make it fixed size and auto scrolling in single line
   `android:ellipsize="marquee" android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"`

Comment: thanks i reduced the fontsize and made width to wrap_content.I have set android:singleLine="false";  android:ellipsize="marquee"  android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever", but the whole text doesnt get displayed in multiple lineline

Answer (score 0):

Just allow the TextView to be of multiple lines

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

This will allow TextView to continue to another line if it requires.

Comment: android:singleLine="false" i did add this , but it doesnt work , some part of the text is still missing

Answer (score 0):

for multi line text you must set `android:singleLine="false"` in your text view xml file
after that for going to next line you must place `\n` in your string like this
`textView.setText("Hello \nHi");`

Comment: if the string has value something like asdfghjklqwerty@asdf.com, textview does not display the whole text, it displays only some part of it